# How is division before multiplication in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I run some code and I get same results with or without parenthesis, even if I know that multiplication have higher precedence then division. Here is example:

```
let calculate = 16 / 30 * 100
```

I gott same result as

```
let calculate = (16 / 30) * 100
```

So I don't know which of them has higher precedence.

Comment: *"even if I know that multiplication have higher precedence then division"* that's a pretty big assumption. Multiplication and division have the same priority, and they associate left-to-right. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: Well first of all, JavaScript uses PEMDAS just like math equations should. Whichever comes first, multiplication or division, will be executed. After parenthesis and exponents of course.

Comment: About [operator precedence in JS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/operator-subtractprecedence-javascript)

Comment: @Josh I guess "PEMDAS" itself would hint that multiplication comes before division?

Comment: @MátéSafranka - It's better written vertically. It's really (PE)(MD)(AS).

Comment: For Americans: PEMDAS = BODMAS; [more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for explaining further.

Comment: There's something deeply ironic about the mnemonic acronym for operator precedence needing parentheses.

Comment: @MátéSafranka - I have **never** twigged to that. I love it!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just wanted to add that I've seen both PEMDAS and BODMAS in American schools. (although I've seen PEMDAS more)

Comment: @TJWolschon - Yeah, I understand PEMDAS is more U.S., BODMAS more UK. My comment above should have been "For Brits:" not "For Americans:" (I'm both, so I get confused sometimes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this fiddle: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRB0CCQOKZT2

the code is evaluated in this order:

- Parentheses
- Multiply and Divide
- Addition and Subtraction

If you have Multiple and Divide in the same equation then it evaluates the first one it encounters. you can override this by using parentheses.

Answer (score 8):

> So I don't know which of them has higher precedence.

Neither, they have the same precedence and associativity; see [MDN's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for details.

Almost all programming languages adhere to PEMDAS:

- PE - **P**arentheses and **E**xponents
- MD - **M**ultiplication and **D**ivision
- AS - **A**ddition and **S**ubtraction

...aka BODMAS:

- BO - **B**rackets and **O**rders
- DM - **D**ivision and **M**ultiplication
- AS - **A**ddition and **S**ubtraction